# Memory Per Core

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, cluster

I am using the super computers in the network provided by Compute Canada and in the [documentation](https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Job_scheduling_policies) page I see the following:

[image]

I am quite curious - what is the concept of memory per core here? I thought all cores should share the same memory normally? Does it mean that, if I have a job that takes 16GB memory space, and the memory per core is only 8GB, I need at least two cores (i.e. multi-processing) to accomplish it?

Comment: They most likely have some sort of VM provisioning system.  When you run a job they spin up a VM for it to run on and said VM needs CPU/memory specifications, they have set them at 4 or 8GB of memory per vCPU (core).

Comment: So should I care about the memory per core or just the memory per node is sufficient? (i.e. if there are 32 cores, 32 cores * 8GB_per_core = 256 GB RAM per node. If I have a job that requires 100 GB RAM, will it go through?)

Comment: I don't know for sure but I believe so.  In my experience most cloud computing platforms provide packages with similar metrics, but ultimately it is simply a virtual machine with the given specs.

Comment: Ask them. Could be simple language that RAM is given as in 1 CPU 4GB, 2 CPUs 8GB... Only them can clear that out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a particular service, isn't likely to be useful to the public at large, and should probably be directed at the administrators of said service.

Comment: @ilkkachu I agree that this question is probably better directed toward those managing the service but you haven't given sufficient reason as why it _shouldn't_ be here. The fact is, this question at hand involves terminology of a *nix cluster which is not off-topic.

Comment: @nabulator agreed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search for your question via Google like this - '[Compute Canada memory per core](https://www.google.com/search?q=Compute%20Canada%20memory%20per%20core&oq=Compute%20Canada%20memory%20per%20core&aqs=chrome..69i57.9067j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)' you'll be directed to the [glossary of terms for Compute Canada](https://www.computecanada.ca/research-portal/accessing-resources/glossary/). On that page they define it like this:

> **Memory per core:** The amount of memory (RAM) per CPU core. If a compute node has 2 CPUs, each having 6 cores and 24GB (gigabytes) of installed RAM, then this compute node will have 2GB of memory per core.
>
> **Memory per node:** The total amount of installed RAM in a compute node.

I'd also direct you to this page titled: [Allocations and resource scheduling](https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Allocations_and_resource_scheduling). They cover in excruciating detail how they handle the billing/scheduling of jobs that are RAM vs. core heavy.

> A **core equivalent** is a bundle made up of a single core and some amount of associated memory. In other words, a core equivalent is a core plus the amount of memory considered to be associated with each core on a given system.
>
> **Cedar** and **Graham** are considered to provide *4GB per core*, since this corresponds to the most common node type in those clusters, making a core equivalent on these systems a core-memory bundle of 4GB per core. **Niagara** is considered to provide *4.8GB of memory per core*, make a core equivalent on it a core-memory bundle of 4.8GB per core. Jobs are charged in terms of core equivalent usage at the rate of 4 or 4.8 GB per core, as explained above. See Figure 1.

So I do not believe this has anything to do with NUMA in the traditional sense. It's more the case that the Canada cluster management group has arbitrarily decided what a "core equivalent" is with respect to the different compute clusters they provide.

Their Graham + Cedar clusters provide 4GB/core, whereas Niagara provides 4.8GB/core.

The concept would appear to be completely a logical segmentation at the job/scheduling level of their compute cluster.

Comment: So ... Does it mean that I need 50 GB per core to run a job that takes 50 GB memory?

Comment: Or rather, can one core use another core's RAM?

Comment: It means that if you have a job with a specific RAM requirement, your request will get however "core equivalents" are required to provide that amount, and you'll be "charged" in usage accordingly.

Comment: So I will be charged with idle core as well (because i used their RAM)?

Comment: That was my interpretation of the compute cluster material.

Comment: The x86_64 Linux kernel can handle a maximum of 512 to 4096 Processor threads in a single system image. Each CPU core / thread add approx 8 KB to the kernel memory use. So if you had a 64 core system would need 512 KB or ram for task scheduler, or 4 GB for a 512 core setup. Or 32 GB for the max.

Answer (score 2):

What's you're looking for is NUMA repartition see the wikipedia page for that.

[numa wiki schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#/media/File:Hwloc.png)

it is harware bus design optimised for faster access between core & memory 
but also allows core to address memory of any another core (this is just slower in that case)